# Duplicated Service Name Error when Replacing CAR in WSO2 Micro-Integrator

Tags: wso2-micro-integrator

I have created a Proxy Service and place it as a CAR application into the WSO2 Micro-Integrator 1.2.0 in the path `/home/wso2carbon/wso2mi-1.2.0/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps`. I can query the new proxy service without any issues, but when I delete the CAR application and replace it with a new version of the CAR, I got an error in the Micro Integrator:

```
...
Caused by: org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: ProxyService named : MyCustomProxyService already exists
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.handleSynapseArtifactDeploymentError(AbstractSynapseArtifactDeployer.java:482)
    at org.apache.synapse.deployers.ProxyServiceDeployer.deploySynapseArtifact(ProxyServiceDeployer.java:66)
    ... 20 more
```

I thought that by removing the CAR application, it would delete the Proxy Service, but clearly is not working like this.

If I delete the problematic CAR application and restart the WSO2 Micro-Integrator service, then, when I place the new CAR application (again), the error is no presented.

Is there a way to clean any installed Proxy Service (CAR Application), without restarting the WSO2MI server?

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the carbon application all the deployed artifacts should be removed from the server and according to your issue description, it seems the hot deployment feature is not working. However, When I checked this locally in both fresh and updated WSO2:MI-1.2.0 pack, I am able to deploy the same changed car application without any server restart. So please download the **LATEST RELEASE: 7.1.0** from the official site[[1](https://wso2.com/integration/#)] and try it again.